How to Avoid Duplicate Contribution IDs in SearchKit Report with Payment Processor Grouping?
I'm trying to build a report in SearchKit to list all contributions within a specified date range, grouped by Payment Processor and then by Financial Type. The goal is to see contributions grouped by these categories without duplicate entries skewing the total count.
Current Setup:

I start with a Contribution search as the base.
To access the Payment Processor data, I add Contribution Financial Trxns to the search.
The grouping works as expected, showing contributions by Payment Processor and then by Financial Type.

Issue:
The problem is that my results include duplicate Contribution IDs, resulting in inflated counts. It appears that each Contribution Financial Transaction linked to a contribution creates a separate row, even if it’s already accounted for, making it hard to get an accurate total.
Question:
Is there a way in SearchKit to:

Filter out contributions that have a Contribution Financial Transaction record, so only unique contributions are shown in the final count?
Alternatively, is there a method to group results in a way that avoids duplicates when contributions are associated with multiple financial transactions?

Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
